# IE closes the div on click

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

I am not sure where the problem is to give a suitable title but i have given what i observe right now. I have a website that works fine for most browsers except for IE. I am currently testing it with IE9 , notice few issues with it. I really dont understand where the problem is , so i am stuck.

This is the link http://www.justobituary.com

As tested with IE9 ..

1. Click "New Obituary" at the top right corner, a div opens up.
2. Click anywhere in that div(form) it quickly closes it.
3. Clicking on any of the input elements(text/textarea/date) works fine. Going by tabindex one by one works fine, but when u directly click on the select , it closes the div

F12(developer tools) does not help much to explain what happens when u click anywhere in that div. It does not happen with any of the other div's in the page.

Let me know if you guys know whats going on or what could possibly the problem that i can quickly try to fix. There are several things that i need to test in that form but they are all stuck since it does not let me enter anything as it closes quickly.

I have *not* given the code(unless you ask for it) since this looks to be a browser compatibility issue with IE according to me, since it just works fine for all the other browsers.

Part of the code is given below ..

....

```
    $("#postNow1").on("click",function() {
                if ( $(".submitForm").is(":visible")) {gotoTop(0);}
            else {  ..
            delayInterval = 0 ; 
             $(".submitForm input.required,textarea.required,select.required").not('input[type=file]').each( function () {   
                $(this).delay(2000 + delayInterval).effect("highlight",  {  color: "YELLOW" , times: 2}, 1500);
                delayInterval += 500;
            });
         }
                    $(".submitForm").slideToggle();

                });
....

$('body').on('click', '#submitNotice', function(e){
      ... check the variables and submit the form through ajax ...
 });
```

Those who do coding extensively for IE can fix this in minutes i believe. Any pointers ?

**LAST HOUR UPDATE :**

1. event.stopPropagation() does not help but "return false" on the "div click" makes the div stay without closing.
2. without "return false", these work A) all input text/textarea/date fields B) accordion expand/collapse fine C) checkbox against Terms & conditions
3. i understand FileReader is yet not supported for

So the problems are still not resolved.. Any Pointers to address 2A,2B,2C with the "return false" ?

UPDATE : I have fixed all the problems. As it was guessed rightly, it must have been due to the event bubbling that created a lot of issues. I created separate form, one for FF and family and other for IE , dealt with them separately by adding required 'e.PreventDefault()' and 'return false' wherever required to make it work. No "div" click's or "select" click handler's required in my case. Thanks everyone. I accept one of the best answers here shortly.

Comment: Probably won't fix your problem but updating your jquery from 1.8.3 to 1.11 will deal with many compatibility issues.

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt Incorrect. This will introduce more compatibility issue if you only upgrade the jQuery version. From 1.9, there are a lot of jQuery functions deprecated / removed.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Do you think the issue i pointed here was looking trivial to fix ? I never do coding for IE so i am not surprised to see issues popping up when i finally do the compatibility check in IE. Does it look like these are fixable ? I have already added a note in my website to say it is still not compatible for IE but i dont wish to live with it forever... lol..

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt I quickly tried with jquery2.10 but that did not address the problem i reported here. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Hi @Param - i reckon its event bubbling of something that would close the form.. but whats worrying is the div itself has "display:none;" even when shown, can you show the code behind the new obituary button?

Comment: Crazy thing is, that the drowdown works if you click the dropdown and hold your mouse pressed until you aren't over the unexpanded dropdown field. After that you can select every option expect the one which is currently selected. If you click the currently selected or somewhere else on the page it still crashes. So basically it crashes everytime when something like "set new selection to previous selection" is performed..

Comment: @JF,I suspect the same but just not sure what it is. That div "submitForm" which does not have "display:none". It is toggled to show/hide when the "New Obituary" is clicked. You can check the "inspect" once again.

Comment: @Param I'd rather you update the question with the code behind the new obituary button if possible. it should be something like `$('.submitForm').slideDown();` but if its different to that there may be a problem with it.

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt Your observation is right. There is no code that watches on "change" of the "select" so i dont think that is causing any issue. Also if you notice the default selected values are not showing up in IE where as in FF it shows selected.

Comment: @JF it is $(".submitForm").slideToggle(); I will paste some part of the code in a short while.

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt probally the plugin used for the dropdowns is preventing propogation by default. It must be the click event bubbling up to a close event somewhere along the lines.. Param - you can use event prevent propagation in the code to stop bubbling.. or define the close event better.. the only thing that should close that popup is the X button.. so make sure that's defined correctly.

Comment: @Param How do you select the default value? In the html select options (even in firefox) there seems to be no selected="selected" or something like that. Do you do select the default value with javascript?

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt I just added a code like  $("div").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            return false;
        }); that made the div stay stable without crashing. Thanks for the pointer. But this brings in more issues like the submit button does not work, and the fileupload clicks does not work. How do i isolate them ? Regarding the selected="selected", its my bad, i changed it to "<option selected>" but that did not help show up the selected in IE.

Comment: Ignore the default select, it could be resetting due to the javascript code that resets all the values in the form when newly opened. but the other problem of submit,fileUpload not working after the e.preventDefault is added still stays. How do i isolate them so that we fix this problem all together. thanks for helping.

Comment: code pasted... can anyone help please ?

Comment: these are my observations in the trial&error of last several hours ... but i am back to square1 as the problems are still not resolved.
event.stopPropagation() does not help but return false does.
without "return false", these work 1) all input text/textarea/date fields 2) accordian expand/collapse fine 3) checkbox against Terms & condition
with "return false", while it fixes the div getting closed issue, 2 and 3 does not work
in both the cases, fileupload accepts the pic, tells me the filepath but the FileReader does not work.